# Why Can't I Fit 2GB of Video onto 4GB DVD?

Tags: dvd, storage, format, disc

I have 15 X 20 minute videos (174MB each = 2.61GB total). I'd like to burn them onto a 4.7GB DVD but my software tells me there's not enough space on the disc.

What can I do to make these videos fit? They're .avi format if that helps!

Comment: What system are you doing this on?  What commands or tools were you using?  Show us what you were doing and maybe we can figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Windows DVD Maker.  [Here's a screenshot of the error message I receive when I add my videos to the list](https://postimg.org/image/6nhta47jb/)

Comment: Look at your own screenshot. The software thinks that your videos are `500MB` each, not `174MB` each.

Comment: Right - I'm thinking maybe the software encodes the videos into a new format that expands their size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are not burning it as a "data DVD". The software you used is for burning a "DVD-Video" (i.e. playable even on the most conventional DVD players that doesn't even support DivX/Xvid or so). The videos will be re-encoded in to H.262 stream in one of the standard resolutions ANYWAY.

A single layer DVD-Video can typically contain at most 2 - 2.5 hours of video (unless the software you use allow you to make the DVD-Video using a VCD resolution), while you are trying to fill it with double of that; not even a double layer disc is necessarily enough.

Ref.: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DVD-Video

Comment: probably correct

Comment: thank makes sense - thank you! Time to fork out for a multipack